# Couchdb 2.1 Master Master replication of all databases

Tags: couchdb

I am setting up a 2 node cluster of couchdb, but I am unable to figure out how can we do a master-master replication of all databases automatically.

We have thousands of databases that needs to be replicate across the nodes, because we are using couch pouch synching mechanism per user basis. (One database per user)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no mechanism like this. You may write your own script for starting replication for each DB in _all_dbs